# Magento - Get session GrandTotal?

Tags: php

Right now i am using Mangeto 1.9.1 and i am trying to get the GrandTotal value of the session order in external php file in the main Magento directory.

Here is my php file:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
    $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
    require_once $mageFilename;
    $app = Mage::app('default'); 
    Mage::app();


    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    $quoteData= $quote->getData();
    $grandTotal=$quoteData['grand_total'];


    echo "Grand: - $grandTotal";
?>
```

But it's not printing the value of the grand total.
Where is my mistake how i can make this thing work ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hi You `can not access magento current session` to outside magento application

But you c`an create a magento session out side magento`.
As want  the `GrandTotal value of the session order in external php file` in the main Magento directory. then just send current quote id to this php and 
load the quote object from using quote id

I `donot why you have send` this quote object t`o external php file in the main Magento directory.`

I am  suggesting to send use this file as lib file and  helper  file

**Edit**

you can do this by using magento event observer so create a module

**Step1:**

```
app\code\local\Stackexchange\Magento42858\etc\config.xml
```

and code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento42858>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento42858>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <magento42858>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento42858_Helper</class>
      </magento42858>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <magento42858>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento42858_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>magento42858_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </magento42858>
    </models>
    <events>
      <checkout_submit_all_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <checkout_submit_all_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>magento42858/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>sendmyrequest</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </checkout_submit_all_after_handler>
        </observers>
      </checkout_submit_all_after>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Step2:define helper class Data.php at pp\code\local\Stackexchange\Magento42858\Helper\
and code is

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento42858_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**Step3:** create Observer.php `at app\code\local\Stackexchange\Magento42858\Model`  which  trigger a function on order place  and `send a post request using curl and send grandtotal as parameter`

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento42858_Model_Observer
{

    public function sendmyrequest(arien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $BillArray = array(
        'firstname' => urlencode('amit'),
        'lastname' => urlencode('bere'),
        'street' => urlencode('kolkta'),
        'company' => urlencode('test'),
        'email' => urlencode('dev.amitbera@gmail.com'),
        'grand_total' => $order->getGrandTotal()
);


        $Billparams='';
        foreach($BillArray as $key=>$value) {
            $Billparams .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
        }


        $url=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB).'yourfileldDir.php';
        $Curl=curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($Curl);
        //grab URL and pass it to the browser
        curl_setopt($Curl,CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($Curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$Billparams);
        curl_setopt($Curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $result = curl_exec($Curl);
        curl_close($Curl);
    }

}
```

As i send post request to your php file and send grandtotal As post paramete then you can 
it by  below code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['grand_total'])){
echo  $_POST['grand_total']
}
```

Comment: How i can make this ?

Comment: can you please tell why you send grantoatal to this php   and when?

Comment: I want to send this thing to this file so when i get the GrandTotal i can devide it by half for one process which i want to make to my store. Can you help me get the Grand Total ?

Comment: after addtocart a product from magento ui interface?

Comment: plaese specify event  just lie after order pace,after addtocart etc?

Comment: After processing an order.

Comment: What is doing the function `sendmyrequest` What this thing is sending ? Do i need it ?